# Error en python: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

```
def solicitar_texto():
    texto = input("Ingrese un texto :")
    print(len(texto.split() ))
    while len(texto.split())< 5:
      texto += " " + input("continue ingresando hasta alcanzar el min solicitado:")
    return texto


def enlistar_palabras(texto):
    texto =solicitar_texto()
    l_palabras =texto.split()
    l_palabras_validas=[]
    for palabra in l_palabras:
        print(palabra)
        if(("po" in palabra) or (palabra[:4] =="gene") or (palabra[-4:]=="cion")):
           l_palabras_validas.append(palabra)
    return l_palabras_validas
```

Tengo que ingresar un texto que no sea menor a 5 palabras y en la otra función    ver si alguna palabra termina en "cion" , comienza con "gene" o en alguna parte de la palabra tiene "po".Me da el error en l_palabra = texto.split().

Comment: Donde dices `texto = solicitar_texto` tienes que hacer `texto = solicitar_texto()`. De este modo llamas a la función y guardas lo que ésta te retorne. Sin los paréntesis, no estás llamando a la función sino asignando a la variable `texto` **la propia función** en vez de el valor retornado. De ese modo `texto` pasaría a ser una función y por eso te da el error de que no puedes hacerle `split()` (no es una cadena, sino una función)

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar te recomiendo que tu lista vacía `l_palabras_validar=[]` la declares al inicio.
Para tu expresión lógica no debes usar los slicings `[:]` pues estos son para los elementos de las listas, no para evaluar los strings, para esto puedes usar los métodos `startswith` y `endswith`
Finalmente te aconsejo revises el nombre de tus variables, pues tenias unos "tipos" y por lo tanto las llamadas eran erroneas.

Espero este código te pueda servir:

```
l_palabras_validar=[]
def solicitar_texto():
    texto = input("Ingrese un texto :")
    print(len(texto.split() ))
    while len(texto.split())< 5:
      texto += " " + input("continue ingresando hasta alcanzar el min solicitado,")
    return texto
texto=solicitar_texto()

def enlistar_palabras(texto):
    l_palabras = texto.split()
    for palabra in l_palabras:
        if(("po" in palabra) or (palabra.startswith("gene")) or (palabra.endswith("cion"))):
            l_palabras_validar.append(palabra)
    return l_palabras_validar

sol = enlistar_palabras(texto)

print(sol)
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En la funcion enlistar_palabras no es requerido el parametro texto ya que se esta haciendo la llamada  `texto =solicitar_texto()`

Y se puede estar reduciendo codigo sin estar declarando variables que son utilizadas una unica vez, al mismo tiempo se puede estar utilizando *list comprehension* para lo que se estara retornando en `enlistar_palabras`

```
def enlistar_palabras() -> list:
    texto =solicitar_texto() 
    return [palabra for palabra in texto.split() if 'po' in palabra or palabra.startswith('gene') or palabra.endswith('cion')]
```